# Number of different plate arrangement numbers

Tags: combinatorics

You have 10 plates which must be placed next to each other, each of which can be represented as a curly brace.
Each plate can either be opened to the left: }, or to the right: {.

The 10 plates can be placed in many different ways, like in this arrangement: {{ }}} {{ }}}.

In the above arrangement, there are 4 *groups*, a group being a continuous sequence of plates which are all opened either right or left (in the above case, the groups would be 2R, 3L, 2R, 3L).

Suppose that you've arranged the plates such that there are $n$ groups. A *plate arrangement number* is calculated by taking the number of plates in each group, $p_1, p_2,...,p_n$, and dividing $1$ by the sum of their reciprocals. Thus, the formula for the plate arrangement number is: $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{p_1}+\frac{1}{p_2}+...+\frac{1}{p_n}}$$

In the above example, the plate arrangement number would be: $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}} = 3/5$.

What are the total different unique plate arrangement numbers that can be created with 10 plates if you must use all 10 plates in each arrangement?

To solve this question, I thought about using the stars and bars method, and summing over all bars, the stars representing the plates and the bars representing the groups (i.e. sum the number of arrangements with 10 stars and 0 bars all the way to 10 stars and 9 bars), which represent the number of ways to create 1 group of plates to 10 groups of plates from the 10 total plates, since each set of groups is associated with a plate arrangement number.

However, I realized that I would be overcounting, as }}{{{{{{{{ and }}}}}}}}{{ would be considered distinct arrangements by stars and bars but would yield the same plate arrangement number.

Is this the right track to solving the problem? How do I adjust for overcounting, if so? Thank you!

Comment: If you want to count all lists of positive integers that add up to 10, without counting reorderings as distinct, this is the [integer partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)). But notice that reordering isn't the only way to get the same sum of reciprocals. For example, $\frac14+\frac14=\frac13+\frac16$.

Comment: @Karl thanks for putting a name to what I was trying to do. However, I didn't consider your second sentence, and am now more lost...

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a tricky problem. You could paraphrase it as: How many distinct values can $\sum\frac1{x_i}$ take, if $\{x_i\}$ are positive integers that sum to $10$? If all else fails, you could write a little computer program to compute the first few values of this function and then look it up in OEIS.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A212187